# Delegate not nil when prepareForSeque, but nil when called in Navigation Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I have a delegate that I created in a Navigation Controller that has a table view. When I pass my data in from my MainViewController (which I have set as a delegate, and implemented the delegate method) I do through prepareForSegue. Looks like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loadFavorites"]) {
        FavoritesTableViewController *favoriteTableViewcontroller = segue.destinationViewController;
        favoriteTableViewcontroller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

And in the same MainViewcontroller class I do this in the .h file:

```
@interface MainViewController : UITableView <UITextFieldDelegate, FavoriteTableViewControllerDelegate>
```

I also declare the following in the FavoriteTableViewController class:

```
@class FavoritesTableViewController;

@protocol FavoriteTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)favoriteTableViewController:(FavoritesTableViewController *)controller didSelectItem:(NSString *) item;
@end

@interface FavoritesTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <FavoriteTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

And I implement the protocol in my MainViewController:

```
- (void)favoriteTableViewController:(FavoritesTableViewController *)controller didSelectItem:(NSString *)item
{
    self.item.text = [stop substringToIndex:5];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everything compiles, and I can see the delegate being set. However, when the method is called in the tableView delegate here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    NSString *key = favorites[indexPath.row];
    NSString *item = [[FavoritesData getAllFavoriteItems] objectForKey:key];

    [self.delegate favoriteTableViewController:self didSelectItem:item];
}
```

The delegate is set to 0x0, or nil. Which means it isn't calling back to the MainViewController class to execute the code. I'm still a little week on delegation. I know how it works, but when it doesn't I usually get a little lost. What am I doing wrong?

By the way, in storyboard, the NavigationController has a TableViewController in it, and that sets the class to FavoriteTableViewController. That all works fine and good because I am using NSUserDefaults to pass data toward the modal view. All I am trying to do now is select data, dismiss the view, and set the data to the main view.

Comment: Is the segue going to a nav controler? and have you tried putting a log in the [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loadFavorites"] if statement? I don't know how many times I didn't put the right string in there to check.

Comment: Yes it is going to a nav controller.

Comment: I posted an answer for you, but doesn't explain why it didn't crash when you set delegate. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your delegate is being released... so you should retain the mainVC somewhere... 

Though from you've described its odd that it is being released given that it's in the Nav stack.

Temporarily, maybe keep a retain pointer to it in your app delegate singleton. If that is the problem consider making it a permanent reference. Or changing the logic to not rely on a delegate between controllers in your navigation stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are segueing to a nav controller you should have to get the nav first. However it should have crashed if you were setting the delegate.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loadFavorites"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;

        FavoritesTableViewController *favoriteTableViewcontroller = navController.childViewControllers[0];
        favoriteTableViewcontroller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your MainViewController also embedded in the navigation controller?

If not, it probably gets deallocated before the delegate method call.

Try to **temporarily** set the delegate to **strong** and see if this will make a difference. Don't forget to change it back to weak to avoid potential retain cycles afterwards.

Comment: Setting it to strong didn't help. Also the MainViewController is within a TabBar Controller, not embedded in the navigation controller. I just sequel to the nav controller (which may be my problem, I don't know).